# When writing a custom serialization, what is the difference between using SerializerProvider or jsonGenerator to generate the json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, customserializer

I was trying to write a custom implementation for serializing an object like explained in here: [Jackson custom serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

Where I have:

```
    @Override
    public void serialize(
      Item value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
 
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);

...
}
```

But, I noticed that I could also use the SerializerProvider to write the same thing in this other way:

```
    @Override
    public void serialize(
      Item value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
 
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        provider.defaultSerializeField("id", value.id, jsonGenerator);
...
}
```

So I was wondering: what is the difference between:

```
    jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
```

and

```
    provider.defaultSerializeField("id", value.id, jsonGenerator);
```

Comment: `JsonGenerator.write*Field` provides bunch of method for each type to serialize a data element..and you have to manually pick the method name during coding.  `SerializerProvider.defaultSerializeField(String, Object, JsonGenerator)` takes any value in the second parameter and picks the correct serializer for the given type with a loaded list of Serializers.

Comment: You can navigate through the source code of these methods yourself to find more. `Ctrl + Click` is all you need.